# Get day name from Datetime using SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to get day name from the given datetime using the SQL Server 2008 R2.

**Example**:

Given date:

```
'2014-11-14 00:00:00'
'2014-11-15 00:00:00'
```

Expected result:

```
Date              Day Name of Date
----------------------------------
2014-11-14        Friday
2014-11-15        Saturday
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
select DATENAME(weekday,getdate())

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), '2014-11-14 00:00:00', 105) AS DATE,
       Datename(weekday, '2014-11-14 00:00:00')         AS DayNameofDate
```

Answer (score 2):

The function you need is DATENAME.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DATENAME` function

```
DECLARE @currentDay DATETIME = GETDATE(); -- 3 Apr 2019
SELECT DATENAME(dw,@currentDay);

-- Output:- Wednesday
```